# Use a proof by case to show that $\gcd (m+n,mn)-\gcd (m,n)$ is even for all integers $m$ and $n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that $\gcd (m,n)= m a+n b$ and $\gcd (m+n,m n)=(m+n)c+m n$ for some integers $a,b,c$, and $d$,and I know that we have to reach that

$\gcd(m+n,mn)-\gcd (m,n)=2 k$  for some integers . My problem is what is the relationship between $a,b,c$, and $d$?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. What do you mean by "we have to reach that..."? Are you saying that is what you are also given, or that you need to prove that? And what do you mean by "for some integers"? Do you mean for some integer $k$?

Comment: Hint: Instead of using the results you've given here, consider the four cases obtained by letting $m$ be odd / even and $n$ odd / even

Comment: Hi, thank you for your respond, we have to prove that the answer is a even number

Comment: This is my idea, beacause as you know even numbers are in format of 2k  for some integers k so if we prove that in some how gcd (m+n,mn)-gcd (m,n)=2k or any even number we have done.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the parity of $m$ and $n$.

If $m$ and $n$ are both even, then clearly $m$, $n$, $m+n$ and $mn$ are all divisible by 2, which means $gcd(m,n)$ and $gcd(m+n, mn)$ are both even. So $gcd(m+n,mn)−gcd(m,n)$ is even.

If $m$ and $n$ are both odd, then $gcd(m,n)$ is clearly odd. $mn$ is not divisible by 2, then $gcd(m+n, mn)$ is also odd. $gcd(m+n,mn)−gcd(m,n)$ is even.

If $m$ and $n$ has different parity, then $gcd(m,n)$ is odd because one of either $m$ or $n$ is odd. And since they have different parity, $m+n$ is odd. So $gcd(m+n, mn)$ is also odd. Thus $gcd(m+n,mn)−gcd(m,n)$ is still even.

Hence $gcd(m+n,mn)−gcd(m,n)$ is always even.